# Jquery sortable: How to change font-size for the row that was dragged

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th nowrap align="left" >Sort</th>
      <th nowrap align="left" >User</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="sort">
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Jay</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Mike</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Jenny</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Fiona</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>   



$( "#sort" ).sortable({
    stop: function( ) {
      $(this).css('font-size', '20px');
   }
});
```

I am using Jquery sortable on a table, I want to change the font-size of the row that was last dragged and dropped, so the users know which row they just dragged, I have the above JS, but it is setting the css for 2 rows, seems to the the row that was dragged and dropped and the row after it, instead of just the row that was dragged and dropped.

I am new to JS and am very confused as to why this is happening and what to do to fix it.

Any helps is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you post the whole code please?

Comment: @N.Malloul I added the HTML for the table, above JS is all I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change out your function with

css file

```
.enlarge {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

js file

```
$("#sort").sortable({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).find("tr").removeClass("enlarge")

    $(ui.item).addClass("enlarge");

  }
});
```

You just want to add and remove the font size whenever you want to drag and drop.

http://jsfiddle.net/ayang10/fTXRQ/4/